# Generate a random file key

Tags: elixir

I need to generate a random file key. It has to validate the following regular expression:

```
~r/[A-Z0-9]{8}/
```

What is the best way to generate such a random String in Elixir?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd create a binary with all possible characters and then choose one of the randomly using a random integer generated using `:rand.uniform/1`:

```
defmodule A do
  @bytes "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
  def random(length) do
    for(_ <- 1..length, do: :binary.at(@bytes, :rand.uniform(byte_size(@bytes) - 1))) |> List.to_string
  end
end

for _ <- 1..10 do
  IO.puts A.random(8)
end
```

Output:

```
J0C924EG
N9VOSW2Y
GRGYHTQH
I7HMWUCY
T3GRBSB7
VT5XU405
I7ZQNENP
1KDR9YLG
JB3BCYWC
8NZUPXZ1
```

Note that this random output is not cryptographically strong. The Erlang documentation recommends using `:crypto.strong_rand_bytes/1` for that but truncating its output to `[A-Z0-9]` is a bit more code than the simple one I wrote above.

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty (and probably not the best solution in the world), but something like this would work.

```
defmodule RandomKey do
  @charset Enum.to_list((65..90)) ++ Enum.to_list((1..9))

  def generate(size \\ 8) when is_integer(size) do
    char_list = for _ <- 1..size, do: do_generate()
    Enum.join(char_list)
  end

  defp do_generate do
    char = Enum.random(@charset)
    if char > 9 do
      List.to_string [char]
    else
      to_string(char)
    end
  end
end
```

Calling `RandomKey.generate/1` would give you a default key of 8 in length, but you could optionally specify a different size.